# How can I assign an id for radiobutton and access it at code behind in Xamarin Forms in order to not check both radiobuttons

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

xaml code

```
<input:RadioButton  x:Name="button1" Clicked="Radio_Button_Clicked" 
       Grid.Column="1" Value="btn1" 
       Style="{StaticResource radiofontsize}">
</input:RadioButton>

<input:RadioButton x:Name="button2" Clicked="Radio_Button_Clicked"  
       Grid.Column="2" Value="btn2" 
       Style="{StaticResource radiofontsize}">
</input:RadioButton>
```

C#

```
private void Radio_Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}
```

Comment: You have already assigned ids to your buttons. `x:Name` corresponds to their ids.

Answer (score 0):

You have already assigned the `StyleId` to your buttons which is the `x:Name` setting in the XAML.

Try the below code. It will help you.

```
private void Radio_Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var styleId = (sender as RadioButton).StyleId;
    if(styleId == "button1")
    {
        //Do your logic here for the button1 selection.
    }
    else
    {
        //Do your logic here for the button2 selection.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like @Harikrishnan said, you could also use `ClassId`.

```
 <Button ClassId="btn1" x:Name="button1" />
        <Button ClassId="btn2" x:Name="button2"  Clicked="button2_Clicked"/>

 private void button2_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var btn = sender as Button;
        var id = btn.ClassId;

        //.....
    }
```

Or you could use `FindByName` to get the name id of button control.

```
 var s = this.FindByName<Button>("button1");
```